# User settings not working for formatting PowerShell code

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I am saving the following in Visual Studio Code user settings (`settings.json`) and saving, restarting Visual Studio Code, but it's not working.

```json
"powershell.codeFormatting.openBraceOnSameLine": false,
"editor.formatOnType": true
```

What I want it to do is when I type:

```
if (1) {}Enter
```

I want it to do this:

```
if (1)
{   

}
```

Not this (default behavior):

```
if (1){

}
```

Those settings should be enough but for some reason it's not taking?

Any ideas?

If I do a format document afterwards (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) it DOES correct the document as specified above, but I want it to auto format on type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it will reformat on typing but it takes a few enters before it will apply them. It has to see enter twice before it will format the braces.

So you basically have to do this:

```
if (1) {
Enter
Type Something Enter
}
```

After the second enter key it will reformat the braces for you.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that still seems like a bug.  If this is the behavior, what the heck is `"powershell.codeFormatting.ignoreOneLineBlock"` even do?

Comment: You can find the issue on GitHub that goes into detail about the format options (can't find right now). It is not a bug, just how they implemented it. If you think about the editor service has to see a keystroke before it can engage so there will be delay in enforcing some formatting.

Comment: Ignore one line block is where formatter block statements that are on one line. It will not expand those out.

Comment: I know what the setting means.  I'm saying `formatOnType` is not working with `ignoreOneLineBlock`.  The point is that `if (1) { 2 }` + Enter doesn't format with `"powershell.codeFormatting.ignoreOneLineBlock": false` and `"editor.formatOnType": true`.  However, if `"editor.formatOnPaste": true`, then pasting the above code *does* format it.  Similarly, Shift + Alt + F will also format it.  So, if there's two behaviors, which one is right?  And why are there two different behaviors?

Comment: FormatOnType and ignore one line block are not meant to work together. It is one of those that has no effect while you are typing. It takes effect when you are using format document or format selection. With format on paste is equivalent to run "format selection" against what you pasted into the editor. You can see this effect if you paste a large amount of code, it will format into the file as you copied it and takes the editor a few milliseconds to go through and apply the formatting.

Comment: Thanks for input here , I can confirm it's working as you've indicated

Answer (score 0):

Is `powershell.codeFormatting.ignoreOneLineBlock` set to `true`?  It's the default value for that setting.

Comment: Hi, yes it was set to this but even if it's false, it doesn't alter the unwanted formatting behavior. Thanks anyway for the suggestion

Comment: Yeah it doesn't seem to work for me, either.  I've got format on paste enabled, and even with ignore one line block disabled pasting a block like that is ignored.